# DrawableLeft attribute on spinner on Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

When you have a `Button` for example, you can use `android:drawableLeft` to make it an icon at the left of the button:

[image: DrawableLeft in usage]

Now, is there an attribute to use it on `spinner`? `android:drawableLeft` is not an attribute in `Spinner`, so is it possible to have the same result, but in a `Spinner?`

Comment: you must use custom layout.xml for spinner and Adapter for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an unsupported attribute for `Spinner`. You must use a third-party library or make your own XML template for it.